# How to query inside html using laravel PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make something like this.. (the images inside my head)

[image]

and what I want to do is loop the query so I can get what I want just like this.

here is what I tried using Html.

**controller**

```
public function listReportCrew(){
    $id = DB::select('select distinct show_name from view_mastercrewprogram');
    return view('CrewProgram.ListReportCrew.index', compact('id'));
}
```

and here is my Html

**Pages Html**

```
@foreach($id as $program)
<?php

$db = \App\ReportViewAll::where('id', '=', $program);
?> 
<div class="card shadow m-3">
<div class="card-body m-2 p-2">
<div class=" mt-5 ml-2 mr-3">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h4>{{$program->show_name}}</h4>
        </div>
  </div>
  @foreach($db as $report)
  <div class="row">
        <div>{{$report->employee_nik}}</div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 @endforeach
```

my code doesn't show the `$db->employe_nik` that's why what happens at this?

this is what I thought, just like I want to query the data and insert into `$db` variable and after that just passing that value using `$db` and looping at much each of every item and so on. How do I get to that?

Comment: then what sould i do then?, i want my html layout be like that. and what should i post if not image and change it to text?

Comment: `<div>{{$db->employee_nik}}</div>` should be `<div>{{$report->employee_nik}}</div>`, isn't it ?

Comment: @JazZ sory, it's type, but the data still not there. I don't know how to get the data

Comment: Try to fetch your `$id` like this `$id = DB::selectRaw(DB::raw('distinct show_name from view_mastercrewprogram'));`

Comment: @ricky: disregard my former comment. It isn't the case I thought it was.